# Сортировка вектора объектов класса. QuickSort

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graph, qsort

Задача: Найти минимальное остовное дерево графа с помощью алгоритма Краскала. 
Сортировку нужно реализовать самому (пользоваться библиотечной сортировкой нельзя, лабораторная работа по проге)).

Реализация: для хранения графа

**graph.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

const unsigned short MIN_DIST = 0;
const unsigned short MAX_DIST = 1023;
const int MAX_NODES = 50;           // Максимальное кол-во вершин
const int MAX_EDGES = 1225;         // Полный граф с N вершинами имеет N(N-1)/2 рёбер

// класс ребра
class Edge
{
private:
    std::string FirstV, SecondV;    // вершины между которыми связь // имя вершины в паре с цветом
    int FirstVcolor, SecondVcolor;
    unsigned short dist;        // вес ребра с диапазоном 0-1023, проверяеться при вводе
public:
    // конструктор
    Edge() : dist(0), FirstVcolor(0), SecondVcolor(0), FirstV(""), SecondV("") {}
    unsigned short getDist() const {
        return dist;
    }
    void setDist(unsigned short dist) {
        this->dist = dist;
    }
    friend class Graph;
};

// класс Графа
class Graph 
{
private:
    std::vector<Edge> edges;            // ГРАФ - по сути массив ребер с вершинами
    std::vector<Edge> disjointSet;      // Минимальное остовное дерево Disjoint-set/Union-find Forest

    int colorOf(std::string str);
    void sortEdges(std::vector<Edge> disjointSet, int begin, int end);
    void quickSort(std::vector<Edge> edges, int begin, int end); //сортировка ребер по возрастанию
    void swapSort(std::vector<Edge> edges, Edge one, Edge Two);  // свап для сортировки

public:
    // конструктор
    Graph() : edges(0), disjointSet(0) {}
    void initGraphfromFile();       // Инициализация ГРАФА
    void sortQuickSort();           // сортировка по возрастанию весов ребер
    void Kruskal();                 // алгоритм Краскала
    void sortEdgesMST();            // Сортировка вершины в лексикографичеком порядке   
    void printUnionFindForest();    // вывод минимального остогого дерева на экран
};
```

Проблема: При сортировке вылетает, выдает это (см. рис.)
Сортировка

**graph.cpp**

```
void Graph::sortQuickSort() {
            quickSort(edges, 0, edges.size()-1);
            std::cout << std::endl << "Сортировка ребер по возрастанию весов успешно завершена!" << std::endl;
        }

void Graph::swapSort(std::vector<Edge> edges, Edge one, Edge two) {
    Edge temp;
    temp = one;
    one = two;
    two = temp;
}

void Graph::quickSort(std::vector<Edge> edges, int begin, int end) { // ?????
    int i = begin;
    int j = end;
    int pivot = (int)(edges.size() / 2); // Выбор опорного элемента -- центр массива

    while (i <= j) {
        while (edges[i].getDist() < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (edges[j].getDist() > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swapSort(edges, edges[i], edges[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (j > begin) {
        quickSort(edges, begin, j);
    }
    if (i < end) {
        quickSort(edges, i, end);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу указать на ошибки, при возможности предложить решение. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявили  в классе фунцию_член  `void quickSort(std::vector<Edge> edges, int begin, int end);` а при определении `edges` у вас ссылька. Сигнатура должна быть одинаковая...

P.S. по поводу вашего кода можно сделать много замечаний:

- Конструкторы должны инициализировать все свои объекты-члены через
  список инициализаторов, если это возможно. Это более эффективно, чем присваивание внутри тела конструктора.
- Уберите деструкторы из классов, они вообше не нужны. Дайте
  компилятору генерировать нормальный деструктор.
- Константным обьектам нужно дать возможность вызвать свои селекторы
  (например  Edge::getDist()), поэтому и во избежании случайных ошибок (попыток записи) они должны быть константными
  методами  (  например   `void Edge::getDist() const`)...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в реализации сортировки - она "тупая" и при обращении к i j элементам массива, выходит за рамки массива (отрицательные или больше реального размера массива).